# Images always at the bottom of the page no matter how long

Tags: html, css

I have a main centre column with a fixed width of 1000px and margin:auto.

Out side this fixed with column, if the user has a screen width greater than this 1000px, I want to have a background image in the extreme bottom left and right corners of each of my pages no matter how long the content is on the page or how wide the users screen is.

In otherwords, if the content on the screen is so long that you need to scroll, then initially you wouldn't see the images because they would be at the bottom of the page.

Likewise, if you resized your browser window the images to the left and right would move in toward the main centre column.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT

```
    <style>
    html{height:100%;}
    body {

        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'DINMedium';
        font-size:16px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background: #e0dcd3 url(../images/mainbg.png) repeat-x;
        min-height:100%;
        }
    #leftBottomImg{position:absolute; bottom:0px;left:0px; background:url(../images/leftBottomImg.png);height:330px;width:300px;}
    #rightBottomImg{position:absolute; bottom:0px;right:0px; background:url(../images/rightBottomImg.png);height:330px;width:300px;}
    #slFooter{width:960px; margin:auto;height:400px;background: #e0dcd3 ;padding:20px;}
</style>

<body id="indexHomeBody">

    <div id="mainWrapper">


    <div id="headerWrapper">
        <div class="left">
            <div id="logo"><a href=""><img src="includes/templates/ceon/images/logo.png" alt="" width="273" height="58" /></a></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>


    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="contentMainWrapper">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">


        <div id="slideshow">
            <div id="nav"></div>
            <a href="#"><img src="includes/templates/ceon/images/banner1.jpg" width="1000" height="369" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="includes/templates/ceon/images/banner2.jpg" width="1000" height="369" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="includes/templates/ceon/images/banner3.jpg" width="1000" height="369" /></a>
            <a href="#"><img src="includes/templates/ceon/images/banner4.jpg" width="1000" height="369" /></a>
        </div>



        <div id="homeMidNav">
        </div>

        <div style="clear:both"></div>

        <div id="homeBestSellers">
        </div>

    </td>

      </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="leftBottomImg"></div>
    <div id="rightBottomImg"></div>

    <div id="slFooter"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you pls show us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/6t5WW/2/)

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%; height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid silver;

}
.main {
    width:100%; height: 600px;
     background: url('http://www.mojowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Cat-Wallpaper-1.jpg') no-repeat right bottom,
    url(http://www.mojowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Cat-Wallpaper-3.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
    background-size: 20%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .main {      
      background-size: 25%;
}


}
```

Comment: ooh.. This is close but I wanted the cats to be on the outside of the center column. at the very right and left hand edge of the screen rather than the column

Comment: yup, this more or less did it. I don't think I need the media query though. But either way, it appears to be working ok at the minute - cheers!

Answer (score 0):

check the below jsfiddle. Are you looking like that?

```
.main {
margin: auto;
width:52%; height: 600px;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid silver;

}
body {
width:98%; height: 600px;
 background: url('http://www.mojowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Cat-Wallpaper-1.jpg') no-repeat right bottom,
url(http://www.mojowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Cat-Wallpaper-3.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
background-size: 22%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
.main {  
 background: none;
}
   body {
  background: url('http://www.mojowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Cat-Wallpaper-1.jpg') no-repeat right bottom,
url(http://www.mojowallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Cat-Wallpaper-3.jpg) no-repeat left bottom;
background-size: 22%;

}

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6t5WW/1/